# Deleting or Closing an Answered Question if Off Topic

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, down-votes, close-reasons, off-topic

I have a question elsewhere which has been voted down, and has 2 votes to close it.

I think anonymous down votes are supremely unhelpful, and that topic has been discussed already. However, I accept that the question can be regarded as off topic, and so it would be appropriate to close or delete it.

I don’t think I am able to close the question, but I can delete it. However, I get the warning about being blocked from asking. The problem is that while it’s live, it runs the risk of more (anonymous) down votes.

The question is: **if I agree that the question is off-topic, what is the most suitable action to take?**

Comment: Both having highly-downvoted and undeleted questions (particularly if they're also closed), and moderately-downvoted deleted (and unclosed) questions contribute to a potential question ban, but neither is definitive until it's the "final straw" which pushes your "bad question asker" measure over whatever the magic, secret threshold is. So, if it's off-topic and can't be changed with reasonable edits (i.e. without completely changing the question), delete it. But if it can be salvaged through judicious edits to make it both on-topic and upvoteable, that is definitely the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you agree the question is off topic, and if the answer has no upvotes, by all means go ahead and delete it.

The warning is correct, too many deleted questions might lead eventually to question ban, but it's not instant, and you'll have chance to improve before it takes effect. But asking an off topic question is worse, and having it downvoted and closed will have greater impact towards question ban anyway.